# How to use append command in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to save data into a `.mat` file. When I add data for a second time it overwrites the previously stored content. I used the following command but is not working:

```
save('newAnswer.mat','dat','-append');
```

with

- `newAnswer.mat -> matFileName`
- `dat -> arrayName`

Comment: when you say this is not working, does it produce an error? (it should not). What are you trying to do? You want to overwrite the existing mat file? Or do you want to save it as a new mat file?

Comment: i want to add new row in dat array..

Answer (score 0):

The `'-append'` option adds a *new* variable to the file. If you want to save the same variable, it will update the existing value of the variable in the file. If you think of it, makes sense—you can't have two variables with the same name in workspace, so you can't have two variables with the same name in the .mat file.

The workarounds are at least two: either 1) copy your variable in a new one, and save *that* variable:

```
 dat1 = dat;
 save('newAnswer.mat','dat1','-append');
```

or 2) create a cell array of values for each new value that you want to save, and update *that* variable:

```
 %'before everything else'
 dat_history = {};

 %'. . .'
 dat_history{end+1} = dat;
 save('newAnswer.mat','dat_history','-append');
```